# How to enter a date in Google Spreadsheet without hyphens or slashes

Tags: google-sheets

Is there any way to enter a date in a Google Spreadsheet without having to type hyphens or slashes?

Comment: Are you looking for a datepicker-type widget or do you mean you just want to enter everything in DDMMYYYY format and have the sheet parse it?  If it's the former, see http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/17238/adding-a-datepicker-in-google-spreadsheet

Comment: In principle, yes. If you're good in mental arithmetics, you can figure out the number of days that passed since December 30, 1899, enter that number (e.g., 42559) and format as a date. But perhaps you'd like something more practical. What practical date format, without hyphens of slashes, do you have in mind?

Comment: What signal will you use to tell Google Spreadsheets that you're typing a date?

Comment: Very good question. I also have this question. For example, if I want to enter 20231203 and it automatically be converted to 2023/12/03, then what should I do? None of the answers or comments pointed out answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, like this:

`July 13` (will default to current year), or `July 13 2016`.
Both will register as a date value.

If your locale is not English, you might have to use a different format and/or month name.

Once you have entered something that is recognized as a date in a cell, you can double-click the cell. This will open a date picker, which allows you to select a different date. 
Or, as @jonsca suggests, [add data validation to the cell to get a date picker](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/17238/adding-a-datepicker-in-google-spreadsheet).